# Wygwam - Empty Paragraphs

Tags: wygwam

Is there anyway to stop Wygwam from pasting empty paragraphs when i paste text into it ? It got the latest version 3.02

I got the "ignoreEmptyParagraph" thing turned on and still not working.

Thanks fro the help

Answer (score 1):

In the same setting location as "ignoreEmptyParagraph", set "autoParagraph" to NO.

[image: WYGWAM Advanced Settings]